# R handles some characters differently when installed with apt / compiled from source

Tags: r, ubuntu, non-ascii-characters

R 3.4.4 from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
> "µV"
[1] "\302\265V"
```

Same computer, R 3.4.4 (and also 3.2.0, and also 3.5.1) compiled from the sources obtained from CRAN:

```
> "µV"
[1] "µV"
```

I'd rather prefer the second behaviour. Where does the difference come from?

`Encoding("µV")` returns `"unknown"` in the first case and `"UTF-8"` in the second case, but setting the encoding of a string variable manually doesn't seem to improve its representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `Sys.getencoding()` was different in those two builds. Running `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "en_US.UTF-8")` on the first build seems to have fixed the issue.